# Mysql select only latest row when column value changed

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302915/mysql-select-row-when-column-value-changed) but only 1 difference. the mysql is as follows.

```
ID |    lat   | lng          | timestamp    
1  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00  
2  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:03:00  
3  | 23.21584 | 84.37877     | 2016-01-01 00:06:00  
4  | 23.21584 | 84.37877     | 2016-01-01 00:09:00  
5  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:12:00  
6  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:15:00  
7  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:18:00  
8  | 23.21465 | 84.37856     | 2016-01-01 00:21:00
```

although there is a change in lat(latitude) and lng(longitude) in rows 3 and 5 here in this case it should select only row with id 5 only.

The algorithm would be as follows:

(a) arrange the table in acsending order of timestamp

(b) check last row i.e. 8th row. compare latitude , longitude values with row 7. if they are same precede to compare with row 6 and so on until there is a change in latitude and longitude values . here in this case it would be row 4. then print row 5

(c) if the 8th row and 7the row latitude,longitude values are different then do nothing.

EDIT: In a nutshell, I'm simply after the earliest instance of the current values, or the last time the values changed.

Comment: have you tried the accepted answer. If your DB version is 8, then even no need to use such assignments, rather window analytic functions.

Comment: I don't understand, why only row 5. an algorithm needs deterministic rules, to work. Properly. the link would deliver 3 rows.

Comment: Are you simply after the earliest instance of the current values (I.e., the most recent change)

Comment: @nbk this is use to determine that the vehicle is stopping at that location for how much time. the table is the output of the gps tracker

Comment: @Strawberry , it is the earliest instance of the current values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first record when the latitude changed the last time?

Then here's a way to get that.

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table YourLatiLongiTudesTable
> (
>   ID int primary key auto_increment, 
>   lat decimal(8,5) not null, 
>   lng decimal(8,5) not null,
>   `timestamp` timestamp not null
> );
>
> insert into YourLatiLongiTudesTable
> (lat, lng, `timestamp`) values                              
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:00'),
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:03'),
> ('23.21584', '84.37877', '2016-01-01 00:06'),
> ('23.21584', '84.37877', '2016-01-01 00:09'),
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:12'),
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:15'),
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:18'),
> ('23.21465', '84.37856', '2016-01-01 00:21')
> ;
> ```

**Query for MySql 5.7**

> ```
> --
> -- Using variables
> -- First calculate a rank on descending date
> -- Then calculate a rownum based on the rank
> --
> SELECT id, lat, lng, `timestamp`
> -- , rnk, rnk_rn
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , CASE 
>     WHEN rnk != @prev_rnk
>      AND @prev_rnk := rnk
>     THEN @rn := 1
>     WHEN @prev_rnk := rnk
>     THEN @rn := @rn + 1
>     END AS rnk_rn
>   FROM
>   (
>     SELECT t.*
>     , CASE 
>       WHEN lat != @prev_lat
>        AND @prev_lat := lat 
>       THEN @rnk := @rnk + 1
>       WHEN @prev_lat := lat 
>       THEN @rnk
>       END AS rnk
>     FROM YourLatiLongiTudesTable t
>     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk:=0, @prev_lat:=0) v
>     ORDER BY `timestamp` desc, id desc
>   ) q1
>   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @prev_rnk := 0) v
>   ORDER BY `timestamp`, id
> ) q2
> WHERE rnk = 1 
>   AND rnk_rn = 1
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |      lat |      lng | timestamp          
> -: | -------: | -------: | :------------------
>  5 | 23.21465 | 84.37856 | 2016-01-01 00:12:00
> ```

**Query for MySql 8.0+ (and other RDBMS that support window functions):**

> ```
> --
> -- Using window functions
> -- First calculate a rank by summing changes.
> -- Then calculate a rownum based on the rank
> --
> SELECT id, lat, lng, `timestamp`
> -- , rnk, rnk_rn
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date(`timestamp`), rnk ORDER BY `timestamp`, id) AS rnk_rn
>   FROM 
>   (
>     SELECT *
>     , SUM(IF(lat=prev_lat,0,1)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC, id DESC) AS rnk
>       FROM 
>       (
>         SELECT *
>         , LAG(lat) OVER (PARTITION BY date(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC, id DESC) AS prev_lat
>         FROM YourLatiLongiTudesTable t
>       ) q1
>    ) q2
> ) q3
> WHERE rnk = 1
>   AND rnk_rn = 1
> ORDER BY `timestamp`, id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |      lat |      lng | timestamp          
> -: | -------: | -------: | :------------------
>  5 | 23.21465 | 84.37856 | 2016-01-01 00:12:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc2d14caad093b8e93ee7996b8cd06b1)*

Comment: Too many assumptions

Comment: @LukStorms rather comparing latitudes, time-stamp compare would be more easier

Comment: @LukStorms the algorithm would be as follows: (a)   arrange the table in acsending order of timestamp (b) check last row i.e. 8th row. compare latitude , longitude values  with row 7. if they are same precede to compare with row 6 and so on until there is a change in latitude and longitude values . here in this case it would be row 4. then print row 5 (c) if the 8th row and 7the row latitude,longitude values are different then do nothing. coding the above in mysql statements is what i need.Thanks

Comment: @bipin_s Ok, I understand it now. Updated.