# MySQL: Extract the date when a value in a column has changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a mysql database that tracks changes in settings. Looks like this:

| date | setting 1 | setting 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | 0.01 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-03 | 0.02 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-04 | 0.03 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-05 | 0.04 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-06 | 0.04 | 0.01 |
| 2021-01-07 | 0.03 | 0.01 |
| 2021-01-08 | 0.04 | 0.01 |
| 2021-01-09 | 0.04 | 0.02 |
| 2021-01-10 | 0.05 | 0.02 |
| 2021-01-11 | 0.06 | 0.02 |
| 2021-01-12 | 0.06 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-13 | 0.07 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-14 | 0.08 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-15 | 0.08 | 0.01 |

I'm looking to get all dates on which 'Setting 2' has changed.
Expected result:

| date | setting 1 | setting 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | 0.01 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-06 | 0.04 | 0.01 |
| 2021-01-09 | 0.04 | 0.02 |
| 2021-01-12 | 0.06 | 0.00 |
| 2021-01-15 | 0.08 | 0.01 |

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You could take a look at the `LAG` function. That could be used to get what you need.

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: @esqew I am not looking for free code, just ideas how this can be achieved. Sorry if I didn't include enough details in the post.

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis I looked into LAG but I am unclear how to show only rows where the value in setting2 changes.

Comment: @Stu some older one, 5 I think. It doesn't support window functions which I guess could be used. Still, I'd accept a window function solution as an answer because I'd like to learn the technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
SELECT `date`,setting1,setting2 FROM  ( SELECT  *,
                        IF(@prevStatus = s.setting2, @rn := @rn + 1,
                        IF(@prevStatus := s.setting2, @rn := 1, @rn := 1) ) AS rn
                FROM setting s
         CROSS JOIN 
                (
                 SELECT @prevStatus := -1, @rn := 1
                ) AS var 
        ORDER BY s.`date`
               ) AS t
        WHERE t.rn = 1
        ORDER BY t.`date` ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/1

**All credential to user: @1000111 :** [Mysql select row when column value changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302915/mysql-select-row-when-column-value-changed)

Answer (score 1):

As you are interested in a window function solution, this will work in MySQL 8, or any platform that supports ansi window functions.

```
select date, setting1, setting2 from (
    select *, case when Lag(setting2,1,-1) over(order by date) != setting2 then 1 end changed
    from t
)t
where changed=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `lag()`.  I would phrase this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(setting2) over (order by date) as prev_setting2
      from t
     ) t
where not prev_setting2 <=> setting2;
```

Note that `<=>` is the null-safe comparison operator.

If you are using an older version of MySQL, well, at this point I would recommend that you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
SELECT date,setting1,setting2 FROM 
( SELECT *,
  IF(@prevStatus = YT.setting2, @rn := @rn + 1,
    IF(@prevStatus := YT.setting2, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
  ) AS rn
 FROM your_table YT
 CROSS JOIN 
 (
  SELECT @prevStatus := -1, @rn := 1
 ) AS var 
 ORDER BY YT.date
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.ID
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302915/mysql-select-row-when-column-value-changed)

Comment: This is my solution to this question. I also edit and add links to the original solution, thanks