# Select and join rows when column value changes per group

Tags: mysql

##### Assessments table:

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| assessment_id | device_id |     created_at      |
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
|             1 |       1   | 2022-07-15 20:03:03 |
|             2 |       2   | 2022-07-15 21:03:03 |
|             3 |       1   | 2022-07-15 22:03:03 |
|             4 |       2   | 2022-07-15 23:03:03 |
|             5 |       2   | 2022-07-15 23:03:03 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

##### Results table:

```
+---------------+---------+--------+
| assessment_id | test    | result |
+---------------+---------+--------+
|             1 |       A | PASS   |
|             2 |       B | FAIL   |
|             3 |       A | FAIL   |
|             4 |       B | PASS   |
|             5 |       B | PASS   |
+---------------+---------+--------+
```

##### Objective

I would like to return a row for each time the `result` of a `test_id` changes.

For example, Device 1 has Assessments 1 and 3. Test A in Assessment 1 was PASS, and Test A in Assessment 3 was FAIL, so we want to return this change as a row.

Device 2 has Assessments 2, 4, and 5. There was a test result change in Assessments 2 and 4 (Test B changed from FAIL to PASS), we want to return a row for this.

We do not want to return a row for Assessment 5 because Test B was PASS, and it was also PASS in Assessment 4. No change.

The resulting table would look like this:

```
+-----------+---------+------------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------------------+
| device_id | test_id | previous_assessment_id | previous_value | previous_value_date  | next_assessment_id | next_value |   next_value_date    |
+-----------+---------+------------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------------------+
|         1 | A       |                      1 | PASS           | 15/07/2022  20:03:03 |                  3 | FAIL       | 15/07/2022  22:03:03 |
|         2 | B       |                      2 | FAIL           | 15/07/2022  21:03:03 |                  4 | PASS       | 15/07/2022  23:03:03 |
+-----------+---------+------------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+----------------------+
```

I've tried playing around with a couple of queries found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560000/sql-selecting-rows-where-column-value-changed-from-previous-row), but they either took a long time and returned the wrong data, or didn't work at all. I don't think this is a duplicate because I'm using multiple tables, and every other question I've seen refers to a single table.

I've also looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302915/mysql-select-row-when-column-value-changed) but could not get the helpful answer to apply to my situation.

I'm having some weird issue getting SQL Fiddle to work, but here is the test schema I've been tinkering with:

```
CREATE TABLE `assessments` (
  `id` int,
  `device_id` int,
  `created_at` datetime
);

INSERT INTO `so_assessments` (`id`, `device_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (1, 1, '2022-07-09 22:56:00');
INSERT INTO `so_assessments` (`id`, `device_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (2, 2, '2022-07-10 22:56:06');
INSERT INTO `so_assessments` (`id`, `device_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (3, 1, '2022-07-11 22:56:11');
INSERT INTO `so_assessments` (`id`, `device_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (4, 2, '2022-07-12 22:56:17');
INSERT INTO `so_assessments` (`id`, `device_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (5, 2, '2022-07-13 22:56:24');

CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `assessment_id` int,
  `test` enum('A','B'),
  `result` enum('PASS','FAIL')
);

INSERT INTO `results` (`assessment_id`, `test`, `result`) VALUES (1, 'A', 'PASS');
INSERT INTO `results` (`assessment_id`, `test`, `result`) VALUES (2, 'B', 'FAIL');
INSERT INTO `results` (`assessment_id`, `test`, `result`) VALUES (3, 'A', 'FAIL');
INSERT INTO `results` (`assessment_id`, `test`, `result`) VALUES (4, 'B', 'PASS');
INSERT INTO `results` (`assessment_id`, `test`, `result`) VALUES (5, 'B', 'PASS');
```

Comment: I was typing out an answer, but I have been interrupted. Look into Window Functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html - in particular the LAG() function.

Comment: Though the downvote was likely because your setup queries are broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8, Window functions can help. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

You can partition *your results* by `device` and `test`, and add a column that is the previous value of the `result`, then use the last row where the result differs from the previous value.

The following query creates a new column in your results with `previous_value`

```
SELECT 
    assessment_id,
    device_id,
    test,
    result,
    LAG (result) over w as `previous_value`,
    LAG (assessment_id) over w as `previous_assessment_id`
FROM assessments join results using(assessment_id)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device_id, test ORDER BY assessment_id)
```

Yields the result:

```
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
| assessment_id | device_id | test | result | previous_value | previous_assessment_id |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
|             1 |         1 | A    | PASS   | NULL           |                   NULL |
|             3 |         1 | A    | FAIL   | PASS           |                      1 |
|             2 |         2 | B    | FAIL   | NULL           |                   NULL |
|             4 |         2 | B    | PASS   | FAIL           |                      2 |
|             5 |         2 | B    | PASS   | PASS           |                      4 |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
```

Which is a big part of the battle. Now we need to take that result and find the row for each device/test pair with the highest assessment_id, where result != previous_value.

The window is calculated after `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and even `HAVING`, so there's not much more that can be done in that query (that I have thought of) to narrow it down to the only the most recent entries for each device/test pair. So the above will have to be a subquery to get the final result.

Note: I am going to assume that if the result never changes, you want to show the first time that result was recorded. In other words, you want to count results with `previous_value = NULL` as a transition.

Here's a query that lists all the times the test result from a device/test pair changes:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    assessment_id,
    device_id,
    test,
    result,
    LAG (result) over w as `previous_value`
FROM assessments join results using(assessment_id)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY `device_id`, `test` ORDER BY `assessment_id`)
) AS t
WHERE result != `previous_value` OR `previous_value` IS NULL
```

gets the result (I left out `previous_assesssment_id` and the others for space):

```
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+
| assessment_id | device_id | test | result | previous_value |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+
|             1 |         1 | A    | PASS   | NULL           |
|             3 |         1 | A    | FAIL   | PASS           |
|             2 |         2 | B    | FAIL   | NULL           |
|             4 |         2 | B    | PASS   | FAIL           |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+
```

**EDIT**

That's the answer to the question. If the first time the value is set is not of interest, just delete the `OR` part of the WHERE clause. There rest of this answer is because I convinced myself the problem was to get the MOST RECENT time the value flipped. I'm leaving it here, but only for interest.

**Carrying On**

This is all the times the outcome was different than previous, plus the first time a result was recorded. Almost there.

It would be tempting at this point to add another window in the outer query to aggregate the rows from above and identify the correct rows. But at least in MySQL 8, nested windows are not supported.

But given that result, we can create a query using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` that gives the assessment_ids of all the rows we ultimately want:

```
SELECT MAX(assessment_id)
FROM (
    SELECT 
       assessment_id,
       device_id,
       test,
       result,
       LAG (result) over w as `previous_value`,
       LAG (assessment_id) over w as `previous_assessment_id`
    FROM assessments join results using(assessment_id)
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device_id, test ORDER BY assessment_id)
) AS t

where result != previous_value OR previous_value IS NULL
GROUP BY device_id, test
```

Which yields:

```
+--------------------+
| MAX(assessment_id) |
+--------------------+
|                  3 |
|                  4 |
+--------------------+
```

Now we know exactly which rows we need; but we built all that data about the previous values, and now we need a way to join the result of that query with the result of the subquery.

Happily, MySQL 8 has a way to stash a query and use it multiple times, called Common Table Expressions, that use the `WITH` clause [docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). So we can create the table with all the fun data, then use it as a subquery to get the id's we ultimately want, and then join that right back with the results we just created:

```
WITH
  transitions AS (SELECT 
    assessment_id,
    device_id,
    test,
    result,
    LAG (result) over w as `previous_value`,
    LAG (assessment_id) over w as `previous_assessment_id`
FROM assessments join results using(assessment_id)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device_id, test ORDER BY assessment_id)
)

SELECT transitions.*
FROM transitions
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(assessment_id) as assessment_id
    FROM transitions
    WHERE result != previous_value OR previous_value IS NULL
    GROUP BY device_id, test
) AS t2 using (assessment_id)
```

Giving us the final answer (with the other columns you can fill in):

```
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
| assessment_id | device_id | test | result | previous_value | previous_assessment_id |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
|             3 |         1 | A    | FAIL   | PASS           |                      1 |
|             4 |         2 | B    | PASS   | FAIL           |                      2 |
+---------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+------------------------+
```

The first part creates a data set that includes all the information about what came *before* each test. Then we write a query that gets the id's of the interesting rows in that query, then we join back to the original data set to fill in all the columns.

Comment: Holy cow, I realize now I added an extra requirement that you only wanted the MOST RECENT time the the value flipped.

Comment: This is one incredible answer, I think I've just learned more from your response here than I would have from a full day of study. I'm using MySQL 8 and I have never used or stumbled upon Window functions. Thank you, sincerely!

Comment: I just wanted to add that this is really fast too. My earlier attempts were between 1 and 15 seconds, your example came in at: 

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 3,327  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.047 sec. (+ 0.016 sec. network) */

Answer (score 2):

You can use windows functions to peek at values of previous or successive rows according to an ordering and grouping.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    a.device_id,
    r.test,
    a.id as prev_assessment_id,
    r.result as prev_result,
    a.created_at as prev_value_date,
    lead(a.id) over(partition by a.device_id
      order by a.created_at) as next_assessment_id,
    lead(r.result) over(partition by a.device_id
      order by a.created_at) as next_result,
    lead(a.created_at) over(partition by a.device_id
      order by a.created_at) as next_value_date
  from assessments a
  join results r on r.assessment_id = a.id
) x
where prev_result <> next_result
```

Result:

```
 device_id  test  prev_assessment_id  prev_result  prev_value_date      next_assessment_id  next_result  next_value_date     
 ---------- ----- ------------------- ------------ -------------------- ------------------- ------------ ------------------- 
 1          A     1                   PASS         2022-07-09 22:56:00  3                   FAIL         2022-07-11 22:56:11 
 2          B     2                   FAIL         2022-07-10 22:56:06  4                   PASS         2022-07-12 22:56:17
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9d3443c1c924efd3c95f8b0eeed8a82).

**Note**: Your setup queries (that I used) include different data, compared to your expected result.

Comment: The sample data is ambiguous; if individual devices can be subject to multiple tests, the partition in the window definitions will need to be adjusted.